# Slow insertion sorting

Tags: haskell, mergesort, insertion-sort

```
insertionSort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
insertionSort (x:xs) = insertionSortIter [x] xs 
    where insertionSortIter sorted []      =  sorted  
          insertionSortIter sorted (x:xs)  =  insertionSortIter (insert x sorted (length sorted)) xs
          insert x list n   --insert x in list at n
                | n == 0    = x:list
                | x < list !! (n - 1)   = insert x list (n - 1)
                | otherwise = firstns ++ (x:other) where (firstns, other) = splitAt n list
-- [1..10000] 30s                    
mergeSort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
mergeSort (x:[])      = [x]
mergeSort  list       = merge (mergeSort list1) (mergeSort list2)
        where (list1, list2) = splitAt (length list `div` 2) list
              merge [] list       = list
              merge list []       = list
              merge (x:xs) (y:ys) = if x < y then x:(merge xs (y:ys)) else y:(merge (x:xs) ys)
-- [1..10000] 2.4s
```

Time of execution is specified with time of building (at 1 or 1.5s). But still you can feel the difference.

Probably the problem is execution of each branch in guard of `insert` function or `firstns ++ (x:other)` is too slow. But in any case, to put the item in the end of the list I need to go through the entire list for O(n).

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: `insertionSortIter` is iterating through O(n) positions and calling the O(n)-time `!!` operator at each iteration, making it O(n^2) just to insert a single item. Don't do that.

Comment: ДМИТРИЙ, glad to see you there. why so slow. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: @DanielWagner, Okay. `!!` and `++` is bad in this case. What I should to do?

Comment: Insertion sort is a `O(n^2)` algorithm. You might be able to improve the code, but it will still be slower than merge sort for large lists.

Comment: @IVlad, In this synthetic tests (`[1..n]`) should work faster than merge sort.

Comment: Inspect the standard library function [insert](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Data-List.html#insert) for inspiration.

Comment: @DanielWagner, lol. thx. ehm my first point is learning algorithms (and haskell). But its wonderful to find out the function with same name and which doing absolutely same.

Comment: In general using indexes on lists is slow and often makes the code hard to read. Using pattern matching and recursion is probably better in most cases. The same problem also holds for the use of `length`, which is O(n), and can in general be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `insert` function is slow. Here's how to do insertion sort:

```
insertionSort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
insertionSort xs = f [] xs
  where
    f rs []     = rs
    f rs (x:xs) = f (insert x rs) xs

    insert x []         = [x]
    insert x rrs@(r:rs) = if x < r then x:rrs else r:insert x rs
```

In case of confusion, the `rrs@(r:rs)` syntax means that `rrs` is the entire list, `r` is its head, and `rs` is its tail.

`insert` goes through the list and puts out all the elements that are supposed to be in front of `x`, then it puts out `x` followed by elements that are supposed to be after `x`.

Comment: Nice, Thanks! In original insertion sort O(n) in best case. So there O(n) in worst case and it seems there is nothing we can do about it.

Comment: You can use foldr instead of f.

Comment: So the final code is `insertionSort (x:xs) = foldr insert [x] xs`. Very nice. For some reason in my mind was the thought that we can not get a list in foldr. Happy to that this stereotype is broken. hmm but with foldr sort works nonlinear slower.